# Querying a table with no Key field

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, having

We have a table that is storing Sales History for Part numbers by Branch. Part #s can exist in one, or many Branches. Columns include the Current month, and 3 previous months. I need to write a SELECT query that will list all the Part #s that have zero Sales History in ALL Branches. Using the sample data I provided, my query should return Part# 56789, but not Part # 12345, as it has sales in the SalesHist02 column. I should note that our actual table has over 290K unique part numbers, and over 1.3 million rows.
Thanks in advance.

[image: Sample Table Data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your current description and sample output, you can use the `HAVING` clause:

```
select partno
from sales
group by partno
having sum(saleshistcurrmo + saleshist02 + saleshist03 + saleshist04) = 0
```